# Getting the key or value from a map if I have the index

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a JSP that has a list of DVDs and want to send list of the selected (checkboxes) to a second page for processing. In the second page I have used :

```
String selected[] = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");
```

to get the list of selected checkboxes. I would like to get either the key OR value (bse I am building a table) of the selected index. eg; if the user selected the first checkbox, -> I want to be able to access either Pirates or 299.

I converted a 2d array into a map as below thinking that if I am able to get the index of the map I would be able to access either the key or value as below:

```
String [ ][ ] myArray = { 
                          {"Pirates", "299"},
                          {"Travellers", "145"},
                          {"Zoopy", "89"},
                          {"Farewell", "67"},
                          {"Junies", "98"},
                          {"WakUp", "55"},
                          {"Space", "100"},
                          {"Solar", "199"},
                          {"Strom", "200"},
                          {"Wind", "200"}
                        }; 

final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(myArray.length);
for (String[] mapping : myArray) {
  map.put(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
}
```

I am however stuck and don't know where to go from here and would appreciate suggestions from those more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Maps don't have indexes, so you'll have to abandon that idea.

You need to use an indexed data structure, such as a `List` or an array. Perhaps a `List` of custom objects, containing the string and integer values would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The Key-/Value-/Entry-Sets of a map are (as you notice) sets, that means unordered lists. So you actually can parse them to lists with indexes, however the index of lements wont be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Finally..This is what I used instead;

```
TreeMap dvdstree = new TreeMap();

// Add some dvds.
dvdstree.put("Pirates", 5);dvdstree.put("Solar",124);
dvdstree.put("Travellers",145);dvdstree.put("Zoopy", 89);
dvdstree.put("Farewell", 67);


//Get a set of the entries
Set set = dvdstree.entrySet();
// Get an iterator
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();

//Used a count keep track of iteration -> compare with name of checkbox
int count = 0;

//Printing into html table
out.print("<table>");

//Gets the selected checkboxes from previous page
String selected[] = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");   

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
//used a count to keep a track of where I am in the List   
count++;

  for(int i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
    if(count == Integer.parseInt(selected[i])){
     out.print("<tr><td>"+ me.getKey()+ "<td>"+me.getValue()+"<td/></tr>");
     //Used this to get value of checkbox so that I could perform arithmetic in my class
     String value= (me.getValue()).toString();
     double valueDouble = Double.parseDouble(value);
     myBean.addPrice(test2);
    }
  }
}

out.print("<tr><td>Total</td><td>"+myBean.getTotal()+"</td>");
out.print("</table>");
```